# Any way to recover the comments from OpenOffice to docx

Tags: openoffice.org, docx

I was revising a paper with someone in OpenOffice 3.2 and made several comments that do not seem to appear when I reopen the .docx file.  Are these comments gone forever? or am I not viewing the file correctly?

I didn't have any warnings or messages when I saved it as a .docx, so I'm not sure if this is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this is too late for you, but perhaps this will help other people out.

There's currently a bug open for OpenOffice as of 3.4.1 that describes this issue. I ran into it myself. https://issues.apache.org/ooo/show_bug.cgi?id=113059

Basically, if you open a .docx file in OpenOffice that has comments, every comments box will display all the comments in the entire document. The workaround for this issue is to first save the file as a .doc from Word and then open the .doc file in OpenOffice instead of the .docx.

It's also important to note that OpenOffice won't save as .docx so in your case, you probably didn't lose anything. If open a .docx file with comments, the comments will be screwed up in OpenOffice. If you then try to save the document, it will prompt you to save as a .doc in the Save As dialog since OpenOffice can't save over the original file. The resulting .doc file will be permanently screwed up with all the comments combined and repeated in every single comments fields. However, this is actually inadvertently convenient here because it prevents the above bug from causing you to permanently lose all comments in the original file by forcing you to save as a new .doc file.

Here's the open bug that shows that you can't save as a .docx: https://issues.apache.org/ooo/show_bug.cgi?id=88355. You'll also notice that it's not an option in the Save dialog.